# Extract timestamp from large string

Tags: python, regex

I have a large string like this:

```
SEND OK HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Access-Control-Allow- l-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,
Phant-Private-Key Content-Type: text/plain X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 300
X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 297
X-Rate-Limit-Reset: 1452931335.777
Date: Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT 
Set-Cookie: SERVERID=; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-197 0 00:00:01 GMT; path=/ Cache-control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

It contains strings like `Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT` The string may be of any time. I want to get this string out of the whole. I know its a very basic question but how can I do it in python.

Not always will string contain substrings like `Date:`.

Comment: Is each setting/attribute (e.g. `X-Rate-Limit-Reset`, `Date`, etc.) always present, always in the same order?

Comment: Are these `>` really exist or just a format issue?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 No, not always

Comment: @Kevin It was a format issue. Thanks I have corrected

Comment: Is the format of the date always the same even if the time and date would change?  I mean would something like "Jan 18, 2016 (Mon) 7:40:23 AM" be possible, or will it always be that same format?

Comment: I've rolled back your question to its original form, before you made two substantive changes that invalidated existing answers. If you like, feel free to accept an answer that answers _this question_ as it stands. If you have a _substantively different question_, create a new question for it.

Comment: @Matthew Format will always remain same

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I guess that's fair.

Comment: This question is a mess. Is the space in `01-Jan-197 0` supposed to exist, or not? It's unclear whether you're asking how to find and parse all dates in the headers of a HTTP request (in which case you should ask *that*) or something else.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Well, I think that doesn't matter since OP doesn't what that, he wants something like `Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT `.

Comment: This question is discussed on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314847/should-we-rollback-to-the-version-which-has-format-issue-because-it-has-alread?cb=1)

Comment: Your headers are broken, is `Access-Control-Allow- l-Allow-Methods` supposed to be `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`? and the line starting with `Phant-Private-Key` looks broken as well.

Comment: Assuming all the mistakes in your post don't occur in the actual data, have you considered using an http header parser instead of regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
import re
datepattern = re.compile("\w{3}, \d{2} \w{3} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \w{3}")
matcher = datepattern.search(string_to_match_against)
print(matcher.group(0))
```

with your example

```
string_to_match_against = """
SEND OK HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Access-Control-Allow- l-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,
Phant-Private-Key Content-Type: text/plain X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 300
X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 297
X-Rate-Limit-Reset: 1452931335.777
Date: Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT 
Set-Cookie: SERVERID=; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-197 0 00:00:01 GMT; path=/ Cache-control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
"""
```

we would print

```
Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT
```

It looks like you are trying to match an http header, and (according to "HTTP: Pocket Reference", O'Reilly, 2000) three formats of date are possible for the Date header:

1. RFC 1123 (Mon, 06 May 1996 04:57:00 GMT) - this is the one in your example
2. RFC 1036 (Monday, 06-May-96 04:57:00 GMT)
3. ANSI C asctime() (Mon May 6 04:57:00 1996)

RFC1123 is recommended, but if we wish to match all any of the three possibilities, we need to design a regex that can select between the three with alternation

```
import re
pat1123 = "\w{3}, \d{2} \w{3} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \w{3}"
pat1036 = "\w+?, \d{2}-\w{3}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \w{3}"
patc = "\w{3} \w{3} \d+? \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{4}"
datepattern = re.compile("(?:%s)|(?:%s)|(?:%s)"%(pat1123,pat1036,patc))
matcher = datepattern.search(string_to_match_against)
print(matcher.group(0))
```

*Note that this approach does not rely on anything being present EXCEPT the date to extract (we don't need the **Date:** text).  If more than one such date occurs, it finds the first.  Use `datepattern.findall` if more than one is desired.*

Answer (score 1):

Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/) module

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.headers['date'])
```

Comment: Really? I think it's a file or just some string. So you can't use `requests` in this case. Also OP said that: *Not always will string contain substrings like `Date:`.*

Comment: @Kevin, I think that this is an request

Comment: OP said "I have a large string like this", so you can't assume it is a request. You have to do it with the information the OP gives. So in this case it's a string and not a request.

Comment: @Thaille, its string is the result of a request, i think that OP use a bad design, and that this should re-examine its design.

Comment: I am getting these headers by AT request through SIM900A. To my knowledge, I don't think I can get just the date header using SIM900A.

Comment: @user3563059, in this case, you should indicate how you receive these lines and with which device in your first post. I have a better understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample you provided, you can approach like this;

```
import re

s = """
> SEND OK HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
> Access-Control-Allow- l-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,DELETE
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,
> Phant-Private-Key Content-Type: text/plain X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 300
> X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 297
> X-Rate-Limit-Reset: 1452931335.777
> Date: Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT 
> Set-Cookie: SERVERID=; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-197 0 00:00:01 GMT; path=/ Cache-control: private
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
"""

pat = re.compile(r'Date:([\s\w,:]+)')

print pat.search(s).group(1).strip()
```

Output:

```
'Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT'
```

Comment: What if "Date:" is not present in string?

Comment: @user3563059 although keys should be present in headers, is the date format uniform?

Comment: I've rolled back your edits to the original state of your answer that answers the original question (which I've rolled back to its original state), as I did with my own.

Comment: ok. but i think the second edit of the question which was made by OP is correct.

Comment: The OP's edit already invalidated existing answers, so I couldn't include its changes.

Comment: I noticed that. but as OP didn't accepted any answer yet it does not invalidate any accepted answer. Answer can be modified according to the question i think.

Comment: The accepted status does not matter (and _cannot_ matter without invalidating the whole concept).

Answer (score -1):

If each setting/attribute (e.g. `X-Rate-Limit-Reset`, `Date`, etc.) is always present in the string and always in the same order, you can just `split()` it a couple times:

```
>>> mystring.split('Date: ')[1].split('>')[0].strip()
'Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT'
```

If it isn't, you can create a simple regex to look for the particular line:

```
>>> re.search(r'Date:\s*(.*?)\s*>', mystring).group(1)
'Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT'
```

Comment: This will work great if "Date:" is always present before. What if it isn't?

Comment: Oh, there's a chance that the keys will be totally absent?

Comment: How about the format of the actual date string? Will it always start with the abbreviated day of the week?

Comment: @user3563059 - And will it always be on its own line? And are the other fields guaranteed to not contain any text that looks like a date string?

Comment: I am going to leave this answer here for historical reasons, as it perfectly answered the original question (which the OP changed after getting answers, instead of asking a new question as is recommended for this very reason), which might be useful to some users.